# is it possible to retrieve state from Redux store for a particular review comments

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-state-management

i do have a react class component with state in it.

```
class NewComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    modalIsOpen: false,
    aa: true,
    bb: false,
    cc: false,
    dd: false,
    ee: 1,
    dd: [],
    cc: [],
    ff: [],
    gg: [],
    vv: [],
    bb: '',
    rr: '',
    bb: '',
    axcx: 'recent',
    zxc: null,
    asd: [],
    qwe: '',
    asd: '',
    xc: false,
    wxc: false,
    zxcc: null,
    zxcxzc: [],
    zxc: {},
    zxc: false,
    zxc: [],
    zxc: null,
    zxc: '',
    imgGroup: aa.imgGroup,
    videoGroup: xx.videoGroup,
    docGroup: vv.docGroup,
  }
}
```

is it possible to store these state somewhere in store and import it to this component.if so can you guys please help me to do so. am new to redux.

Any help will be highly helpful

Comment: not sure what you asking for , this state are in BrowseModalUpload component and where you want to use them ?

Comment: @Ivan   i got a  review comment ,actually state needs to sit in some store. so is there any way we can import

Comment: @midhunk you want to store the object in a seperate file or you want to initialize the state in store(redux store)??

Comment: @sumanthmadishetty comment from reviewer is the management of all state  in this omponent should sit in redux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done easily. What you have to do is add those variables in your reducer to a respective store (let call the store as **youstore**).

**Reducer.js**

```
const initialState = {
    modalIsOpen: false,
    aa: true,
    bb: false,
    cc: false,
    dd: false,
    ee: 1,
    dd: [],
    cc: [],
    ff: [],
    gg: [],
    vv: [],
    bb: '',
    rr: '',
    bb: '',
    axcx: 'recent',
    zxc: null,
    asd: [],
    qwe: '',
    asd: '',
    xc: false,
    wxc: false,
    zxcc: null,
    zxcxzc: [],
    zxc: {},
    zxc: false,
    zxc: [],
    zxc: null,
    zxc: ''
}

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SOME_ACTION:
    ......
}
```

Now, this should be available from your component as props. For this should use **mapStateToProps** method.

**Your_component.jsx**

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
        modalIsOpen: state.youstore.modalIsOpen,
        aa: state.youstore.aa,
        bb: state.youstore.bb,
        cc: state.youstore.cc,
        dd: state.youstore.dd,
        .......
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    someMethod: data => dispatch(somemethod(data)),
  };
};

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
  )(your_Component);
```

To change the value of a state you have to dispatch an action through **mapDispatchToProps**

Comment: i have 1 doubt in the above scenario-so from the above example i need to dispatch an action method whenever i need to change the state?am i right ?

Its mainly popup related code and its value is based on state variable named modalIsOpen. so according to you which one is better to maintain state within the component or using reducer,which user keeps on closing and opens it

Comment: @midhunk yes you can change the values by dispatching an action

Comment: can u check the second part of my question. am sorry ,just geting familiarized with redux

Comment: @midhunk You don't have to add every state to the store. put the state in the store for the ones you are fetching from a sever or the data where you will be accessing from different components. For a modal popup use internal state you don't have to use redux for that

Answer (score 0):

You should not have the state inside the component but if you want to it you need to you need to have2 things a action and a reducer. In the reducer, you just have set the state

```
dispatch(createState(state))
```

you need to add that in your component but I would suggest highly against it. SO the right way to do it create you reducer.js and ad this state there.

```
  const myReducer = (initialState = state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
   ....
  }
};
```

so when you create your reducer just pass the initial state there. I hope that helps!